# How to implement XCUITest with API Calls

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I am new to XCUITest framework. I need to call an API **https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all** getting list of countries and showing in UITableView now as user will click on any cell based on country name next screen will have country name and country flag every thing is working fine now I wanted to implement XCUITest for that I have added function

```
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]

func testTheCountryListAndAllScreen() {
app.launch()
let countryListTableView = self.app.tables["CountryList"]
XCTAssertTrue(countryListTableView.exists, "Country list have data")
let countryListCell = countryListTableView.cells
 if countryListCell.count > 0 {
     for cell in 0..<countryListCell.count {
          let countryCell = countryListCell.element(boundBy: cell)
           countryCell.tap()
           self.app.buttons.staticTexts["Move to info page"].tap()
           self.app.navigationBars.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
           self.app.navigationBars.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
           }
      }
}
```

at app.launch() app is getting crashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make requests with URLSession and access data with JSONEncoder.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder

---

If you want to test your table (while changing its data), use unit tests. If you want to test how interaction with this table affects other UI Elements, use UI tests. For a better understanding about testing in Xcode watch these videos:

- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/413/
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/414/
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/

---

You did not provide the error text of app launching crash, but I think you tried to use XCTest UI testing APIs in a unit test target.

Comment: I am getting this error in my testTheCountryListAndAllScreen() Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I already make api call and shown it in Tableview as well now I have to do UITesting for it

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your app is getting crashed when you run the XCUITest.

What error do you see in the XCUITest results page? XCode captures a screenshot of the app whenever test fails. You can see in the Test Results page.

```
XCTAssertTrue(countryListTableView.exists, "Country list have data")
```

This function you have written might fail, as it could take a few seconds to load the list of countries after making the API call. You might need to use `XCTWaiter()` function to wait for a particular duration of time before it can fail